# Reading variables from config file results in "VARNAME: command not found"

Tags: bash

What is wrong with these lines?

```
FASTAQ1 = "/home/mdb1c20/my_onw_NGS_pipeline/files/fastq/W2115220_S5_L001_R1_001.fastq"
FASTAQ2 = "/home/mdb1c20/my_onw_NGS_pipeline/files/fastq/W2115220_S5_L001_R2_001.fastq"
DIRECTORY = "/home/mdb1c20/my_onw_NGS_pipeline/scripts_my_first_NGS"
```

They are in a .conf file with other similar variables. The only difference is that these three are created with printf

```
printf 'FASTAQ1 = "%s"\n' "$FASTA1" >> "$DIRECTORY/$filename1/scripts/shortcut.config"
printf 'FASTAQ2 = "%s"\n' "$FASTA2" >> "$DIRECTORY/$filename1/scripts/shortcut.config"
printf 'DIRECTORY = "%s"\n' "$DIRECTORY" >> "$DIRECTORY/$filename1/scripts/shortcut.config"
```

When a script I am using open the .confi file its says that FASTAQ1: command not found

Apart from these three, the rest of variables were created manually in a archive .conf file but the script add these three on the go. The only thing I haven't tried because I don't know how to do that is to remove the white spaces before and after the equal simbol?

Comment: `I don't know how` like, how to edit a file?

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: What's a `.conf` file (or is it actually a `.config` file)?  By which I mean, the filename extension does not by itself convey either the expected syntax or the significance of the contents.  That leaves us with very little to go on.

Comment: None of the answers in the duplicate question suggests quoting.

Answer (score 1):

If you intended to `source` your configuration file, you should have used `printf` this way:

```
printf 'FASTAQ1=%q\n' "$FASTA1" >> "$DIRECTORY/$filename1/scripts/shortcut.config"
```

This allows you to store the value safely regardless if it has spaces or quotes.

The error was caused by the assignment command being interpretted as a simple command instead because of the spaces around the equal sign.

Alternatively for Bash 4.4+, you can use `@Q` expansion:

```
echo "FASTAQ1=${FASTA1@Q}" >> "$DIRECTORY/$filename1/scripts/shortcut.config"
```

Answer (score 1):

In bash, this:

```
var = value
```

is not the same as this:

```
var=value
```

The first example runs a command named "var" and passes it two arguments "=" and "value".

The second example sets a variable called "var" to "value".

It was hard to find this detail in the Bash manual, but the difference is between [simple commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Commands) and assigning to variables, or [shell parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters).